# Android: Letting the app remind answer using Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, xml, if-statement, sharedpreferences

I'm currently making a quiz application for Android. Every question has it's own activity. The user can type an answer in a textbox. If the user types the wrong answer nothing must happen and if he types the right answer the app must remember that he finished that question.

Prefiously I heard that I can make the app remember whether the question is answered or not by adding a "*Shared Preference*". I have been looking a long time on internet now, but I still can't find out how the SharedPreference does work.

**Can someone please give an example of how and where I need to add that Shared Preference?**

Here is the code of the function of the button which decides whether you typed the right or wrong answer:

```
            case R.id.guessbutton:
            EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String password = et.getText().toString();
            et.getEditableText().toString();
            if ((password.equals("mc donalds")) | (password.equals("Mc donalds")) | (password.equals("mc Donalds")) | (password.equals("Mc Donalds")) ) 
        { 
            //Here the function must let the app remember that the question is answered.
        }
    else
        { 
            //Nothing will happen here
        }
    break;
```

Comment: So maybe your question should be: how can I refine my Internet search skills? Sorry to sound harsh, but explanation and a code example can be found directly in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: Yes, I saw that before I asked this question, but I didn't get much wiser from it. I'm totally new it

Answer (score 2):

shared preferences are mainly to access data anywhere in the project. I would recommend you to go through these tutorial first [Shared Preference Tutorial 1](http://www.slideshare.net/androidstream/sharedpreferences-tutorial) and [Shared Preference Tutorial 2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
To make it sample, here is example  `
This is how your create shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("UMSPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("UserId", login);  
                            editor.putString("password", password);
                            editor.putString("ABC", Inside);
                            editor.putString("UserType", "S");
                            editor.commit();
```

To access them ..check this

`String usertype = getSharedPreferences("UMSPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE).getString("UserType", "FD")`;

I hope it would be helpful